# For a B787 in cruise, what is the altitude, speed, and angle of attack?

Tags: aircraft-performance, boeing-787

For a Boeing 787 in cruise, what's the altitude, speed, and angle of attack?

I need the reference as well (normal flight cruise)

Comment: What takeoff weight and range of the said flight? Which part of cruise are you talking about?

Comment: Altitude and speed are as assigned by ATC, are they not?

Answer (score 3):

[image]
(B787 Performance Dispatch)

They vary based on the weight, [cost index](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/1984/what-is-cost-index), and if [step-climbs](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/8592/is-the-climb-rate-different-for-short-haul-flight-and-long-haul-flight) are planned.

For the [Long Range Cruise](http://www.boeing.com/commercial/aeromagazine/articles/qtr_4_07/article_05_2.html) (LRC) shown above, the shaded cells are the approximate optimum pressure altitudes.

So for example if the aircraft weighs 500,000 lb, the pressure altitude will be 35,000 feet, Mach number will be 0.849, indicated airspeed will be 291 knots, the turbofan power ratio will be 73.9, or ~74% of available thrust, and the fuel flow per engine will be ~6,300 lb/hr (2,850 kg/hr).

For the angle of attack it will also vary, but no manuals mention those. This post might help calculate it though: [What is the wing angle of attack of a Boeing 737 in cruise?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/5150/14897)